# Get today,this week,this month and this year data in single query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date-range

I am retrieving today's data from db,I want to retrieve this month,this year data as well,Is it possible in single query? or should I go with separate query for each items? 
My query given below,

```
    select sum(it.rate * it.quantity)as sales from invoices i
join invoice_items it on i.id = it.invoice_id
where i.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when i.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) then it.rate * it.quantity
            end) as sales_1day,
       sum(case when i.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) then it.rate * it.quantity
           end) as sales_7day,
       sum(case when i.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) then it.rate * it.quantity
           end) as sales_1month,
       sum(case when i.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) then it.rate * it.quantity
           end) as sales_1year       
from invoices i join
     invoice_items it
     on i.id = it.invoice_id
```